# Inner join with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working with PHP and PDO, and I need to recolect information joining 3 tables:

- photos
- albums
- album_photos

The table have the following structure:

photos:

```
photo_id  (int)
path      (varchar)
nick      (varchar)
date      (timestamp)
```

albums

```
album_id   (int)
album_name (varchar)
nick       (varchar)
date       (timestamp)
```

album_photos

```
album_id (int)
photo_id (int)
nick     (varchar)
date     (timestamp)
```

So, I want to show all the albums with a max of 5 photos for each one, **where the user nick is 'owner'**.

To be shown as follows:

```
album_name_1:
[photo_1]
[photo_2]
[photo_3]
[photo_4]
[photo_5]

album_name_2:
[photo_1]
[photo_2]
[photo_3]
[photo_4]
[photo_5]
```

I only know that something like this can be made with INNER JOIN, but I can't found how I can make it with 3 tables.

There examples or other help that I can get to do this?

Comment: I'm thinking you won't be able to limit to 5 per album in one query. Unless someone knows some clever way of doing that.

Comment: Well, if I can't get that limit, I'm in a trouble: imagine that the album_id = 4 have 10000 photos linked, but I only need 5, is very expensive!

Comment: yes, i'm saying not in one query for all albums, will have to be one query per album most likely. I'm trying to think of a way.

Comment: Sure, I'm thinking like you; but, again the same problem, If an user have 500 albums, then the program will make 500 queries to find the photos of each album. There's a big problem!

Comment: It think i've solved it. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, c.date
FROM    Album a
        INNER JOIN Album_Photo b
            ON a.Album_ID = b.Album_ID
        INNER JOIN Photo c
            ON b.Photo_ID = c.Photo_ID
WHERE   c.Nick = 'owner' AND
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   album_photo d
          WHERE  b.album_id = d.album_id AND
                 d.nick = 'owner' AND
                 b.date >= d.date
        ) <= 2   // <<== change this value to 5
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd5a0/4)

Comment: Testing your answer [edited], I have now this code:
`SELECT  photos.*
FROM    albums a
        INNER JOIN album_photos b
            ON a.album_id = b.album_id
        INNER JOIN photos c
            ON b.photo_id = c.photo_id
WHERE   c.nick = 'tomirgre' AND
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM   album_photos d
          WHERE  b.album_id = d.album_id AND
                 d.nick = 'tomirgre' 
        ) <= 5`
But the console says: `#1051 - Unknown table 'photos'` AND THE TABLE PHOTOS EXISTS. I'm wrong with something?

Comment: He renamed the photos to Photo,but it only gives album id's but not with photos..right..??

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez sorry for that, you didn't give sample records and I used `Photo`, `Album`, and `Album_Photo` in my tables

Comment: @JW. you are returning album ids only but he wants the photos of that respective albums

Comment: @GautamD3164 in the query above, it returns all columns of table `Album`, and one column from table `Photo` which is `date`. Simple. Add `c.*` on the query to display all columns for table `Photo`.

Comment: This only returns me one photo.
I have 2 albums, and one photo for each.

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez can you give sample records? My records generated are just imaginary. As far as I can tell, the query works on my generated data.

Comment: I fix it now, if the user add to some album a photo that don't have that user name, the query doesn't return that photo, so I quit that part in the SQL = "c.Nick = 'owner' AND" after the WHERE statement and this works perfectly!, you are a god!

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez glad to hear that you fiexd it `:D` you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
"SELECT albums.*,photos.id,photos.path,photo_date as Pht_date
 FROM albums 
     JOIN album_photos 
          ON album_photos.album_id = albums.album_id
     JOIN photos 
          ON photos.photos_id = album_photos_id
"
```

But you cont give individual limit for photos where it involved in "JOIN" orelse you need to give individually like

```
$album_ids = "SELECT album_id FROM albums";
```

then for the photos you need to write query liks

```
"SELECT photos.* FROM photos 
 WHERE album_photos.album_id in (".$album_ids.") AND album_photos.nick = 'owner'
 JOIN album_photos
 ON album_photos.photo_id = photos.photos_id 
 LIMIT 0,10
 "
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be resolved using Stored Procedures. Using variables and [loops](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx), you can retrieve the records you desire. Getting only a maximum of 5 records from an album is quite challenging when you only use the basic SQL commands. Sometimes, you cannot derive the right records. I suggest you use Stored Proc. :)