# Inner join statement with limit in one of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-limit

I'm trying to get data from three tables (photos, albums, album_photos),
then the program searches a user's albums in the album table, then look for every album the ID's of the photos in album_photos, and then, for each ID, look at the photos table all data by ID.

Yesterday I asked something like this: [Inner join with 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492646/inner-join-with-3-tables), but now, I think the question is different, I'm wondering how I can add a limit to a request by `inner join`.

So, I'm working now in this code:

```
SELECT a.album_name, a.album_id, c.* 
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN album_photos b ON a.album_id = b.album_id
INNER JOIN photos c ON b.photo_id = c.photo_id
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM album_photos d
  WHERE b.album_id = d.album_id
  AND d.nick =  :nick
) <=5
```

Ok, this code select's the albums that have 5 or less photos. I do not want the code to do that, no matter how many photos have the album, I want to show the album with a LIMIT OF 5 photos.

Other people have told me that you can not do it, I believe that this is not so, because the SQL language is very complex and I think we should have the tool to do it.

Is there any way to do this in a proper way?

*In the link that I'm shared above I put an example about the output data.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: In the link that I shared, you can find the output expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `where` clause to this:

```
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM album_photos d
  WHERE d.album_id = b.album_id and
        d.photo_id <= b.photo_id
  AND d.nick =  :nick
) <= 5
```

This counts the number of photos in order, not just the number of photos in the album.

Comment: Now the output data have a limit of 4 fotos!, how can I change it to show 5 as max?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez . . . I had the comparison backwards.  Try the revised version.   By the way, you should learn to use "sensible" aliases like "a" for album and "p" for photo.  It makes the SQL easier to read.

Comment: Yes, I hope to learn, this is just to tide a job. Could you recommend some books with which to learn right?
And tahnks for your clear ans great answer!

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez . . . I happen to have written such a book, http://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Using-SQL-Excel/dp/0470099518/ref=cm_cr_pr_pb_i.

Comment: I can not believe it's you, I had not seen your name.
I'm starting to study systems engineering and let me tell you I've heard your name very often around here

Answer (score 0):

Since album_photos  has a mapping relationship between photos and albumns, you can specify the number of photos to join on by using TOP:

```
SELECT a.album_name, a.album_id, p.* 
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN album_photos ap ON 
   ap.photo_id = (select top 5 photo_id from album_photos where a.album_id = ap.album_id order by photo_id)
INNER JOIN photos p ON ap.photo_id = p.photo_id
```

The Order by photo_id in the subquery will ensure the same 5 (or fewer) photos are returned

EDIT PER COMMENT.  Modifying to use MySql LIMIT instead of T-SQL TOP

```
SELECT a.album_name, a.album_id, p.* 
FROM albums a
INNER JOIN album_photos ap ON 
   ap.photo_id = (select photo_id from album_photos where a.album_id = ap.album_id order by photo_id LIMIT 0, 5)
INNER JOIN photos p ON ap.photo_id = p.photo_id
```

Comment: This is for MySQL, not TSQL. MySQL uses LIMIT, not TOP.